# How to structure Makefile rules that apply to all subfolders?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have multiple subfolders, each with the same files/structure

```
tests
|- test1
   |- file1
   |- file2
|- test2
   |- file1
   |- file2
```

Now I want to write Makefile rules that apply identically to things in `test1` and `test2`. For that, I need a rule such that the target and the dependencies have the same path.

What I have so far:

```
TESTS = test1 test2
.PHONY : all
all: $(addsuffix /my_program, $(TESTS))

%/my_program : %/file1 %/file2
   clang $< -o $@
```

Unfortunately with that one I get the error
`No rule to make target` AddStruct/my_program', needed by `all'.  Stop.`

Then I tried changing the build rule to use `*`

```
*/my_program : */file1 */file2
   clang $< -o $@
```

But then, `make` will build all the combinations

```
clang test1/file1 test1/file2 -o test1/my_program
clang test2/file1 test2/file2 -o test1/my_program
...
```

Which is not what I intend. I even tried

```
*/my_program : $(@D)/file1 $(@D)/file2
   clang $< -o $@
```

which results in

```
make: *** No rule to make target `(@D)/file1', needed by `test1/my_program'.  Stop.
```

How do I write the rule so the target and dependencies have the same path?

Comment: Do not modify your question after receiving an answer, especially not in a way that invalidates the answer.

Comment: Actually, there isn't.  Whitespace is important in some contexts but not this one.  Nevertheless it's best to get in the habit of _not_ adding extraneous whitespace when invoking makefile functions.

Comment: Yes, @MadScientist, I deleted that comment after I went back and checked, having considered that this might be an exception.  But yes, one does not need to remember or deduce the exceptions if one doesn't insert believed-to-be extraneous whitespace into one's function calls in the first place.

Comment: _In general_ everywhere in makefiles, prefix whitespace is ignored and suffix whitespace is not ignored.  So, `$(addprefix foo/, $(bar))` working as expected is not an exception because it follows the rules.  There are some unfortunate places where that rule is NOT followed, those are the exceptional cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
TESTS = test1 test2

all: $(TESTS)/my_program
```

Variables are simply substituted; there's no "magic" in make that sees that your variable has another word after it and somehow appends that word to every word in the variable.  the above is the same as writing:

```
all: test1 test2/my_program
```

which is presumably not what you want.  You want:

```
all: $(addsufix /my_program,$(TESTS))
```

Using wildcards is really not what you want, since those are expanded when the makefile is parsed.

**ETA**

First, forget about wildcards.  As I mentioned in other questions you asked, they will virtually never do what you want.  Flush the knowledge of using wildcards in makefile rules from your consciousness and stop beating your head against that wall.

You have a rule like this:

```
%/my_program : %/file1 %/file2
        clang $< -o $@
```

A pattern rule is a *template* that tells make, "if you're trying to build a target that matches this template, AND you can find, or build, the prerequisites listed here, THEN you can use this recipe to build that target".

You are not showing us your actual makefile (as we can see from the fact that your error messages don't match this makefile), but if your makefile is translated properly AND if your statement that all your subfolders have the same structure such that both `file1` and `file2` are present, then the error you have shown us cannot happen.

So, one of two things is true: either you haven't correctly transformed your real makefile into this example makefile in some material way, or else it's not the case that every subdirectory really has all of those files.

For a subdirectory that does not have all those files, make will not be able to apply that pattern rule because it doesn't meet the above criteria, and since there are no other rules that it can find to build that target, it will give you that error.

You should look in the directory `AddStruct` (or whatever it's called) and observe that one or both of the `file1` or `file2` files are not present there.

If you then don't know how to proceed, it seems that your rules for how to build things are not fully defined and you need to define them more accurately.  What are the *real* rules for how to build your targets?

Comment: Good catch! Thank you. I was going wrong even earlier than I though. I've fixed the question, since this doesn't fix my original question.